# Image classification with 4-channels images in NPY format in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using convolutional neural network to build a 5-class image classifier with 3000 images.
My input data are stored as .npy file format with shape (1080,1080,4) and this is obtained by
RGB images and edge features (4 channels).
When trying to train the model using a class Datagenerator, I obtain a huge difference between
the training accuracy (acc train = 97%) and the validation accuracy (acc val = 51%).
You find below an extract of my code.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue how can I improve
the validation accuracy.

And is there any way to use the augmentation of Data that ImageDataGenerator gives?

Thank you very much, any help is appreciated.

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=16, dim=(1080,1080), n_channels=4,
                 n_classes=5, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
            

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('data' + ID + '.npy')
            # Store class
            y[i] = self.labels[ID]
            
        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

And there ist the model:

```
model = Sequential()
# Note the input shape is the desired size of the image img_width, img_height with 3 bytes color
# 1____The first convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(1080,1080,4)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) # ,dim_ordering="th")

# 2____The second convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# 3____The third convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

# 4____The fourth convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

# 5____The fifth convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

# F____Flatten the results to feed into a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())    # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

# D____128 neuron in the fully-connected layer
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# D____Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# D____5 output neurons for 5 classes with the softmax activation
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# model compile
opt = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: Do you use the same generator for both of you data sets ?

Comment: Yes, I use it for both.  @Kh4zit

Comment: `training_generator = DataGenerator(train_filenames, labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(val_filenames, labels, **params)`

and i used the model.fit_generator to train the model